# angularjs ui-calendar events displayed incorrectly on calendar

Tags: angularjs, calendar, angular-ui

I am using Angular UI Calendar to display some events on the calendar. Whenever the calendar is loaded for the 1st time, the events extend to next date or shown on some other Date.

However when I change the View(Day/Week) and come back again to Month view, then events are displayed fine. Similarly, after changing month and coming back again to the current month , the events are displayed correctly.[image: Calendar loaded for 1st Time]

[image: After changing view, and coming back to original View]

Also, I've noticed that the calendar height also increases by 95px after changing the view(when displayed correctly).

Why is this occuring. How can I render events correctly for 1st time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with CSS. Solved it.